# JQ to extract value from JSON file and assign to a variable

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I am trying to extract value from a JSON file using `jq` on Ubuntu. When I `echo` out directly, it works and returns the value to the console. But when I try to assign the extracted value to a variable and `echo` out, returns nothing to console.

The following works:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '{"USERNAME":"TRX-101","PASSWORD":":g&fg#/H"}' | jq .PASSWORD
```

The following does NOT work:

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR = '{"USERNAME":"TRX-101","PASSWORD":":g&fg#/H"}' | jq .PASSWORD
echo $VAR
```

My ultimate goal is to use the value from `$VAR` to do other operations within the shell script (ex: send the value to a XML file etc.)

Comment: Nothing jq-specific to this whatsoever -- `VAR = ls`, for example, doesn't work either. Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here -- and fix *everything* it finds; not quoting the argument to `echo`, for example, [can absolutely cause bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), even if they don't show up with simple values being tested.

Comment: Also, `/bin/sh` is `sh`, not `bash`; please tag for the shell you're actually using (and if you *want* to use bash, use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as your shebang).

Comment: ...btw, the specific shellcheck warnings for your bugs are [SC2036](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2036) (assigning pipeline output to variables), and [SC1068](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1068) (using spaces around `=` where they aren't allowed).